# Transfering selected rows from data grid view to another data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

My problem is to transfer selected rows from data grid view to another data grid view. I don't know what to use if I use the primary key and get the values from database to the another database or send the selected row's data from datagridview1 to datagridview2

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `DataTable` and insert all the selected rows to that `DataTable`

```
DataTable GetSelectedRows(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Visible)
        {
            // You could potentially name the column based on the DGV column name (beware of dupes)
            // or assign a type based on the data type of the data bound to this DGV column.
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }

    object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.Selected) continue; // Add only Selected Rows

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;

        dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

You can pass all SelectedRows to new DataGridView using this

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = GetSelectedRows(dataGridView1)
```